# Count multiple columns with group by in one query using Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I am having a table which has four columns(created, expires, activated, renewed) and datatype is DateTime.I want the number of counts for all four columns for each date.

```
table1.objects.annotate(dt=Truncmonth('created')).values('dt').orderby().annotate(Count('dt'))
table1.objects.annotate(dte=Truncmonth('expires')).values('dte').orderby().annotate(Count('dte'))
table1.objects.annotate(dta=Truncmonth('activated')).values('dta').orderby().annotate(Count('dta'))
table1.objects.annotate(dtr=Truncmonth('renewed')).values('dtr').orderby().annotate(Count('dtr'))
```

Above are four different queries which is giving me date and its count. But i want to get date and count of all columns
what i want is date count_dt,count_dte,count_dta,count_dtr. But i am getting date_dt,date_dte,date_dta,date_dtr,count_dt,count_dte,count_dta,count_dtr.
In short, I want to combine the above four queries.

Comment: You’re not going to get an answer if you just ask us to do your homework without showing you’ve done some effort to solve this yourself. Please show the python code you’ve written to try to solve this. And by the way, explain what you mean by “merge”. Sum?

Comment: i am getting the result for single column by
table.objects.annotate(dt=Truncmonth(col1)).values('dt).orderby().anotate(Count('dt))

Comment: please provide me the solution for this

Comment: try `table1.objects.annotate(month=Trunc('created', 'month', output_field=DateField())).values('month').annotate(ne=Count('expires')).annotate(na=Count('activated')).annotate(nr=Count('renewed'))`. That's assuming 'created' covers all the months. If not you'll have some missing months.

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is wrong, it should be `annotate(ne=Count, na=Count, ...)` all in one annotate clause. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Django's `Coalesce` function to pick the first non-null value from all the dates columns and then annotate the various counts for each of the months values:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth, Coalesce
from django.db.models import Count    

table1.objects.annotate(month=Coalesce(TruncMonth('created'), TruncMonth('expires'), TruncMonth('activated'), TruncMonth('renewed)))
    .values('month')
    .annotate(nc=Count('created'), ne=Count('expires'), na=Count('activated'), nr=Count('renewed')
```

The output is a QuerySet with key value pairs for the keys `month, nc, ne, na, nr`.